# Permcalc.exe for .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winapi

Im trying to find the permcalc.exe tool described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165077(v=VS.90).aspx

But i cant find an actual download link.  If i open the Windows SDK command prompt as directed at that link, i get the usual FNF error.

```
permcalc.exe is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

Im trying to find all the sercurity permissions required for a .NET 4.0 dll.

**edit:**

It doesnt have to be for .NET 4.0, i can recompile in .NET 3.5/2/0.  ANything to save me from going through all my source code.

Comment: There is no Permcalc.exe for .NET 4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.0 got a major overhaul in CAS, such as the new transparency stuff would considerably impact the results, so even if you run the 3.5 version, the results will be wrong. If your .NET Framework 4.0 application has `LegacyCasModel` set to true, then the results *might* be more accurate (I haven't tested, I don't even know if the 3.5 version will run on a 4.0 assembly, I suspect not.)

**EDIT**:

If you need permcalc for older versions of the Framework, then you'd have to download the 3.5 SDK. You can download the ISO [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=71deb800-c591-4f97-a900-bea146e4fae1&displaylang=en).

Comment: But the 3.5 `permcalc` tool is not forward compatible for .NET Framework 4.0.